# Downloading content from wp7 to pc?

Tags: windows-phone-7

What capabilities are available for downloading content from the windows phone 7 device to a pc? For example can a user access files saved by an app by connecting it to a pc, or perhaps through wifi connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project offers navigation of the isolated storage file system and two way file transfer via a wcf service running on the host pc. I last looked at it in ctp, so it may need an update for current tooling.

[Rongchaua's blog » Windows Phone – Phone PC Connector through WCF service](http://rongchaua.net/blog/windows-phone-phone-pc-connector-through-wcf-service/)

Answer (score 2):

I you include a web service host in a desktop application, it is possible to sync from WP7 isolated storage to the desktop PC as per [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104371/Getting-to-my-Isolated-Files-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).
Note that I have not tried this myself yet (I saved the reference for future use).

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY way to share files between a PC and a WP7 is via the Zune software and is limited to movies, pictures, music, podcasts, etc.

There is no way for 3rd party apps to transfer files this way.

If you have or are making a 3rd party app the only way to transfer files from a WP7 device is via a web service.